# Alternatives for Tooltips

Tags: tooltips

We are using Micro Focus - Solution Business Manager application for managing projects. We would want embed tooltips within the fields/section that we have created for a particular module. Some of the would be blank and will only be displayed if the user add some data in the using a button. From a UX standpoint what are the best approaches to make the section informative for a user, so that user understands the actions to be taken on a particular section.

Also can you advise if there are any alternatives for Tooltips?

Comment: Have you got a mockup of what you currently have? It sounds a little unconventional really - only giving help and advice after the user has started interacting with a field? What if they don't know what to do with the field - how would they know there was help to be had without starting to use it?

Answer (score -1):

**Placeholder text** can be a good place to start to introduce what is expected of the user before they begin interacting with a field.

Once they have focused on a field, **subtext** could appear beneath the field which elaborates upon the previous placeholder text–providing more context for the user, without the need for a tooltip.

Tooltips can be useful in scenarios where a user has many fields to fill out and–for some reason–these fields can't be spread out across more screens. Then, a tooltip (usually a ?) can be used to 'show' further information.

Bare in mind: if the information is important to the user, it should *never* be hidden behind a tooltip.